# Laravel: Encode share links pass percent sign

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5. Creating manual social share links using data from db and the current url. It works fine but some of the 'stat' fields contain % sign and just using {{$data->stat}} creates an error if the % sign is in the stat. Is there a way to encode the % sign into the {{$data->stat}} text?

```html
@foreach($stats as $key => $data)

<p class="stat">{{$data->stat}}</p>
      
<a class="link-twitter" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{$data->stat}}&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2fhome">Tweet</a>

@endforeach
```

Comment: you need to `urlencode($data->stat)` or else you'll keep getting the error

Comment: Thanks, but where does this go?

Comment: In the Twitter link

Comment: As in /intent/tweet?text=urlencode($data->stat)&url=...

That doesn't work. It literally puts 'urlencode($data->stat)' in the tweet

Comment: Yes but you need to wrap it in the blade syntax `{{}}`

Comment: Nevermind, that worked. "/tweet?text={{urlencode($data->stat)}}"

Comment: Alright, so you're good?